# UITableView - Index out of range when segment selected while scrolling

Tags: swift, scroll, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am getting "`Index out of range`" in `cellForRowAt` when `segmentedControl` index is changed while scrolling the `tableView`.

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlAction(_ sender: AnyObject!) {
        if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
            self.data?.removeAll()
            loadA()
        }
        else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
            self.data?.removeAll()
            loadB()
        }
    }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomCell

        cell.data = self.data?[indexPath.row] ---> Error here
        return cell
}
```

LoadA and LoadB are similar functions

```
func loadA(){
        API.sharedInstance.loadA(start, callback:  { response in
            if let data = response["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                self.data = data
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView?.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Obviously you are resetting `self.data?.removeAll()` & accessing  empty object by index.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first remove all the data but don't reload the table. Then you call an async method that later updates the data in the background and finally gets around to reloading the table view on the main queue.

You need to only update the data model immediately prior to reloading the table view.

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlAction(_ sender: AnyObject!) {
    if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        loadA()
    }
    else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        loadB()
    }
}

func loadA(){
    API.sharedInstance.loadA(start, callback:  { response in
        if let data = response["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = data
                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: To ensure consistency, I'll first reload with empty data, and then reload again with fresh ones

Comment: @CZ54 Why? There's no reason to do that.